# AngularJs pass model value + model name to function in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-controller

```
$scope.populateMap=[{name: "ABC", code: "123"}, {name: "XYZ", code: "345"}]
```

//Want to send model name + value of model Currently  sending ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj

HTML

```
<select ng-model="ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj" ng-change="ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj">
    <option></option>
    <option ng-repeat="i in populateMap" value="{{i}}">{{i.name}}</option>
```

JS

```
// CONTROLLER CODE JSON parse object to get name and code GOT parsedObj
$scope.genericSetLookups=function (Obj) {  // want to do something like get the ngmodel string + the value, currently only value comes in
    Obj.code=parsedObj.code;
    Obj.name=parsedObj.name
};
```

More Explanation: ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj

- I want in my model to store value of lookups in a specific way, with name and code. On the UI I populate using ng-repeat , So when I select a particular value I can either take i.name as display and set value as i.code .
- But if i do that my  ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj.name will be null and the value will get set to  ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj.code by using ng-model ,so that is the reason in value I am taking i, not i.code or i.value ,now in the map i have code and name pair.
- I sent it to a function and parse it, and set the value to ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj.code=inputTofunc.code respectively for name. In this case in the ng-change i pass on the ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj.code ,rather i want to set i from the map to ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj send it to function also the model string which in this case would be "ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj" .
- So for 10 lookups i can write a generic code ,where the model name and model value i can send as parameter to function and set it there, the above way am doing is probably hardcoding values which i want to set to model in a specific format.

Comment: It's clearly not understandable what you trying to do. You questions is horrible formated. Could you please try create a full qualified example of what you are trying and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: ok, let me try to explain a bit more, inside the ng-change can i pass on the value of model + the name of model as string, so that i can use that model name and set values to it.So the name of the model can change everytime i call the genericSetLookups function.

Comment: Why do you need `ng-change` here your model holds your selected value.

Comment: model is currently holding the value of i which is object having name and code from` populateMap`. So when i use `ngchange` and call a function to change the format so that I can set value inside model in a formal like `ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj.code=123,ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj.name=ABC` , not sure if i can do it without ngchange. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NeverGiveUp161 use `.indexOf` to find its index and select it that way. Here is a demo: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sOr6A2Th9JPiGRwjhCNm?p=preview)

Comment: OK, this is not my cup of tea. I realy don't undestand what you are trying to achieve. Instead of focusing a solution you may going to describe what you try to achieve. E.g. by giving a simple example.

Comment: if you pass a model name by string, you can access it like $scope['ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj'].code .Not sure if you're looking for something like this..Sorry but your question is very unclear

Comment: Sorry guys, can you give it a try now. I have added more explanations best to my capability.

Comment: @FleminAdambukulam : exactly want that, how to pass model name as a string, as now the value gets passed to ng-change

Comment: Please come in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166888/i-does-not-mean-i

Comment: Wouldn't it be ng-change="genericSetLookups('ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj',ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj)"

Comment: but nested properties would always create a problem
controller code would need to be something like $scope['ngObject']['MainObj']['specificFormatObj']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to pass the model name as a parameter, pass it as a string like this from html :

```
ng-change="genericSetLookups('ngObject.SomeObject.abc',ngObject.SomeObject.abc)"
```

And in the controller as the model name contains "." we cannot use the name directly as the key. We need to parse the model name. I have cooked something up after searching a bit. Hope it works.

Controller code:

```
    $scope.genericSetLookups(modelName, value){
        Object.setValueByString($scope, modelName, value);
    }

    Object.setValueByString = function(o, s, val) {
    s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
    s = s.replace(/^\./, '');           // strip a leading dot
    var a = s.split('.');
    for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var k = a[i];
        if (k in o) {
            if(i != n-1){
                o = o[k];
            }
            else{
                o[k] = val;
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    return o;
  }
```

Credit must also go to @Alnitak for the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: I am going to give this a try and accept as answer, for now am sure it helped me partially with this line , that was my first requirement `ng-change="genericSetLookups('ngObject.SomeObject.abc',ngObject.SomeObject.abc)"'`

Comment: This worked like charm :) converting was not a big deal for me but to pass the model name and the value :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand your problem and the comments didn't make it clearer for me. What I tried to do is give you an example of how I would handle a select box and the model.

I would loop over the options with `ng-options` and show the selected option by putting `{{selected.name}}` in the template. Ofcourse if you would want to format the selected value in anyway or react to a change  you can use `ng-change`.

Hope it helps.

[Here is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cy1z8hjh/)

Comment: I do not have any problem in populating the value, the values populate properly. My problem actually starts after ng-change , inside that function I want to send the 2 values to my function, 1 which is in ng-model and second as the string of ng-model which would be ngObject.abc or ngObject.xyz , so this field would be dynamic, i need help around this.

Comment: What do you mean with: `1 which is in ng-model`

If the function for ng-change would be `vm.onChange` and the model would be `vm.selected`, how would you want to see the options passed to `vm.onChange`?

Comment: sorry? What do you mean with: – did not get it.

Comment: currently in office, unable to access chat, i would join from home if any of you would be available. Thanks for help, and you updated the comment earlier it was not showing text.

Comment: Okay i've read it again is this what you want? `ng-change="genericSetLookups(ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj, populateMap[ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj.name])"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166895/discussion-between-digijap-and-nevergiveup161).

Comment: In select you can assign the value {{selected.name}} to some model using `ng-model="ngObject.MainObj.subObj.name"`, but then in model i need `"ngObject.MainObj.subObj.code"` so what I am thinking is i just set the model as ' "ngObject.MainObj.subObj"` using the ` value of option` .And on change of this i want to send 2 values to function where 1st would be `ng-model value which could be {name:abc,code:123}' and 2nd should be the name of the model like in this case 'ngObject.MainObj.subObj' so in the JS function i can set code and name myself. For All such type of fields i can dynamically do.

Comment: `ng-change="genericSetLookups(ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj, name of this model as string which would in this case be 'ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj' as a string )"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question. If you want to save in your model the value code + name, maybe this code can help you:

```
 <select ng-model="ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj" ng-options="(ppm.code + '-' + ppm.name) as ppm.name for ppm in populateMap">
 </select>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rd340byj/1/)

Comment: as per your code, can you suggest If i want to pass this model to a function with the current value of model `345-XYZ ` and model name which is essentially `ngObject.MainObj.specificFormatObj` here , so in my function i can use these values copy these to other object in model. like `ng-click=(func(valueOfModel,nameOfModel))` like this my func dynamically take different model name and values.

Comment: If you want to take the full object on your genericSetLookups function try this: 
        https://jsfiddle.net/u46m751m/5/

I hope this helps you